# How to register validators from more than one assembly in FluentValidation?

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have FluentValidators in more than one assembly. In prior versions of FluentValidation, I was able to register like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
  .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyOne>())
  .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyTwo>());
```

But, this now results in the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Linq.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

Is this no longer allowed? If not, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the same error after upgrading *FluentValidation.AspNetCore* from 7.2.1 to 7.4.0 (as well as upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0).

I solved it by only calling `.AddFluentValidaton(...)` once, like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
  .AddFluentValidation(fv => {
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyOne>());
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyTwo>());
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct `syntax` to add as many assemblies as possible.

```
services
  .AddMvc()
  .AddFluentValidation(fv => {
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyOne>();
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyTwo>();
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ClassInAssemblyThree>();
   });
```